# How to Connect Azure Web App/ API App to Classic portals networks?

Tags: azure, networking, azure-web-app-service, azure-api-apps

I have a Azure Web app and API App which are accessing some services from network which is connected to Client's network via old (classic) portal.This networks is already connected to client and Created in Classic portal.

While Creating Web/API App in new portal i am not able to connect to this existing network. Is there any way i can connect these apps to classic portals network?

Comment: Do you have any update about this thread? If it is useful, please mark it as an answer that will help more communities who have the same issue.

Comment: @TomSun : i am following up with Azure team on this. I will update here once done

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way i can connect these apps to classic portals network?

**Yes**, but [VNet Integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#enabling-vnet-integration) only works with apps in a **Standard, Premium, or Isolated** pricing plan. If your WebApp service plan is not in the Standard+ service plan, please have try to [scale your App Service Plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/azure-web-sites-web-hosting-plans-in-depth-overview#scale-an-app-service-plan) to support it. We could get the details steps about how to enable VNet Integration from the [Azure official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#enabling-vnet-integration). The following is the snippet from the document.

[image]

[image]

> **Note**:
>
> If your target virtual network already exists, it must have point-to-site VPN enabled with a Dynamic routing gateway before it can be connected to an app. If your gateway is configured with Static routing, you cannot enable point-to-site Virtual Private Network (VPN).
>
> The VNet must be in the same subscription as your App Service Plan(ASP).
>   The apps that integrate with a VNet use the DNS that is specified for that VNet.
>   By default your integrating apps only route traffic into your VNet based on the routes that are defined in your VNet.
>
> **Enabling VNet Integration with a pre-existing VNet**
>
> The VNet Integration UI allows you to select from a list of your VNets. The Classic VNets indicate that they are such with the word "Classic" in parentheses next to the VNet name. The list is sorted such that the Resource Manager VNets are listed first. In the image shown below you can see that only one VNet can be selected. There are multiple reasons that a VNet can be grayed out including:
>
> - the VNet is in another subscription that your account has access to
> - the VNet does not have Point to Site enabled
> - the VNet does not have a
>     dynamic routing gateway

Related link:

[Create a virtual network (classic) by using the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-create-vnet-classic-pportal)

[Connect virtual networks from different deployment models using the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-connect-different-deployment-models-portal#values)